# Hover Text on code surrounded text

Tags: wordpress, tooltip

Was looking for a way for informational text to show up once the mouse hovers over a few words anywhere within the website. I see that there are some plugins that handle this but they dont seem to do anything witin custom content types created by the site admin.  In addition, tey dont sem to work for specific html tags surrounding the text I wish to be a glossary term.

For example, lets say I have the words "Option 1" between two list tags (li) I would want it to read "Here is text" upon someone mousing over 
"Option 1" which appears in an unordered list.In other words, I specifically want it to work for all instances of "Option 1" that appear enclosed within (li) tags

Is this request too far fetched?  Maybe there is a different way to do this entirely. I just want people to be able ot select options from a checkbox, but have a way to see what those options are *in detail* from that page where they are listed. Tooltips seem to work well for glossary entries so I figured maybe the same could be done.

Seems that most of the tooltip plugins are not setup in lieu of WordPress Custom Content Types.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is simply to add the `title` attribute, like to make a list tag that looks like this:

```
<li title="Here is text">
    Option 1
</li>
```

Of course, this, you can't style, or modify - it's entirely interpreted by the browser. Alternatively, you could look into [creating your](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-script-free-css3-tooltips/) own [tooltips](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-elements/how-to-create-link-tooltips-using-css3-and-jquery/), using Javascript or CSS3.

Comment: Thanks so much. I am not surprised if I have to create my own tooltips jquery or javascript.  The Options will be managed through the Custom Content Type Manager plugin.  I had tried to get one of the Tooltips type plugins to work but it wouldnt recognize any html/php code.

Comment: Only problem is that the <li title text would be an issue since the template for that content type is stated like this in my template (in this case, Im using Custom Content Manager for a product listing)

  `<strong>Available Options:</strong> <?php print_custom_field('product_options', array('<li>[+value+]</li>','<ul>[+content+]</ul>') ); ?><br />`

Comment: Probably would have to be done through Javascript then, unfortunately, if it's that strict on how much of your HTML you can format. :/

Comment: Hmm..seeing if rich hTML popups might work: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DrfXUyYyrLs

Comment: Is it possible that converting the array above to a Json encoded  array might help with what I want to do?

Comment: Rich HTML pop-ups, as per the video, probably won't work consistently across browsers. As for JSON, I'm not sure you'd need a JSON array - not sure what it'd do for you.

Comment: Yeah. Mainly the problem is that an array is a list.  That list of what will show up is going to vary on what is checked by the admin-user on the backend.  So, one product in my custom content type "product" might have "Option 1" and "Option 3" checked.  Another might have "Option 4", "Option 1", and "Option 6" checked.

Essentially each option needs to  have this tooltip annotation show up so people can see elaboration on what that option entails.

Comment: Found this tutorial and it seems to work with dynamic arrays.  Whether it will work with dynamic arrays IN WORDPRESS, Ill have to hope for the best. 

http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/# (see "dynamic content")